# Syntax error on token "" + "", invalid AssignmentOperator

Tags: java

I get the error message specified in the title. Help?

```
public class SumOfTwo {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int five = 5;
        int four = 4;
        int sum = five + four;

        System.out.println(five " + " four);
    }

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to print? `five + four`? `five + " " + four`? etc

Comment: I assume you want `five` and `four` to be converted to a `String`? `System.out.println(five + " + " + four);`

Comment: Fixed. I was trying to print out the values using the variable names. I forgot to put the extra plus signs in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To concatenate variable value with a `String`, you need `+` between them.

Change

```
System.out.println(five " + " four);
```

to

```
System.out.println(five + " + " + four);
```